# How to solve && operands to logical scalar

Tags: matlab, if-statement, logic, logical-operators, operands

After I run the code in matlab, I encounter this error and unsure how to solve it. How can I solve this problem.

> Warning:
>
> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

```
    Jgray = double(rgb2gray(J));
    % Calculate the Gradients
    [dIx, dIy] = gradient(Jgray);
    if max(dIx)<=103 && max(dIy)<=100
        B =  abs(dIy) - abs(dIx);
    else
        B = abs(dIx) - abs(dIy);
    end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If dIx and dIy are matrices (as opposed to 1-D vectors), `max(dIx)` and `max(dIy)` will return vectors.

`&&` and `||` should be used to compare scalars, not vectors.

You **probably** want to type

```
if max(dIx(:))<=103 && max(dIy(:))<=100
```

but I cannot tell for sure, as I dont know what the code is supposed to do :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `&` and `|` for matrixes instead of `&&`, `||` .

`&&` and `||` are short circuit operators. If you think about it, they make no sense for matrixes. For example, the short circuit or -  `||` stops and returns `true` whenever the first argument is `true`.
But how would you extend that to a matrix?