# convert an image to binary form using dec2bin() function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I tried to convert an image to binary form using `dec2bin()` function in MATLAB.
here i got an error showing

> 'Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical
>   scalar values'.
>
> Error in ==> dec2bin at 31 if any(d < 0) ||
>   any(~isfinite(d))

Comment: Maybe your question is related to this other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172789/how-to-solve-operands-to-logical-scalar-matlab

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the function `im2bw` which is made for converting to binary images:

http://www.mathworks.fr/help/images/ref/im2bw.html;jsessionid=ffd69b1a6ad7ebef254b7cb71ac6